# Applying class to only top level odd and even li elements

Tags: jquery

Im looking to change the class of my top level li and im using jQuery to set a class for the odd and evens of the li elements.  The problem im having is its applying an odd and even class to every li element and i only want it to happen to the top level li

here is my jQuery

```
$('.nav li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alternate');
$('.nav li:nth-child(even)').addClass('evens');
```

Comment: can you share a html sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) instead of [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), assuming `.nav` is the top most parent `ul`

```
$('.nav > li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alternate');
$('.nav > li:nth-child(even)').addClass('evens');
```